# Не удаляются картинки из storage firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, storage

В своем приложении на swiftui, которое использует firebase сделал удаление аккаунта. Хочу, чтобы при удалении аккаунта, также удалялись и все его посты. Посты размещаются в разных коллекциях firestore database. Картинки сохраняются в storage.Написал функцию удаления аккаунта. Посты удаляются, аккаунт удаляется, а вот с картинками проблема. Если посты в разных коллекциях, то удаляются картинки из одной коллекции, а другие нет. Вот мой код.

```
func deleteAccount() {
    isLoading = true
    Task {
        
        do {
            guard let userUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
            
            let post = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").whereField("userUID", isEqualTo: userUID)
            let postcats = Firestore.firestore().collection("PostsCats").whereField("userUID", isEqualTo: userUID)
            let postfish = Firestore.firestore().collection("PostsFish").whereField("userUID", isEqualTo: userUID)
            let postbirds = Firestore.firestore().collection("PostsBirds").whereField("userUID", isEqualTo: userUID)
            let blogs = Firestore.firestore().collection("Blogs").whereField("userUID", isEqualTo: userUID)
            
            let reference = Storage.storage().reference().child("Profile_Images").child(userUID)
            
            post.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        
                        let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").document(document.documentID)
                        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                            if let document = document, document.exists {
                                let data = document.data()
                                let imageReference = data!["imageReferenceID"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference1 = data!["imageReferenceID1"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference2 = data!["imageReferenceID2"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference3 = data!["imageReferenceID3"]! as? String ?? ""
                                
                                Task {
                                    do {
                                        
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference1).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference2).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference3).delete()
                                        
                                    } catch {
                                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                print("Document does not exist")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                        Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").document(document.documentID).delete()
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
            postcats.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for documentcats in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        
                        let docRefcats = Firestore.firestore().collection("PostsCats").document(documentcats.documentID)
                        docRefcats.getDocument { (documentcats, error) in
                            if let documentcats = documentcats, documentcats.exists {
                                let datacats = documentcats.data()
                                let imageReferencecats = datacats!["imageReferenceID"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference1cats = datacats!["imageReferenceID1"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference2cats = datacats!["imageReferenceID2"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference3cats = datacats!["imageReferenceID3"]! as? String ?? ""
                                
                                Task {
                                    do {
                                        
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReferencecats).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference1cats).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference2cats).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference3cats).delete()
                                        
                                    } catch {
                                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                print("Document does not exist")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Firestore.firestore().collection("PostsCats").document(documentcats.documentID).delete()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            postfish.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for documentfish in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        
                        let docReffish = Firestore.firestore().collection("PostsFish").document(documentfish.documentID)
                        docReffish.getDocument { (documentfish, error) in
                            if let documentfish = documentfish, documentfish.exists {
                                let datafish = documentfish.data()
                                let imageReferencefish = datafish!["imageReferenceID"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference1fish = datafish!["imageReferenceID1"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference2fish = datafish!["imageReferenceID2"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference3fish = datafish!["imageReferenceID3"]! as? String ?? ""
                                
                                Task {
                                    do {
                                        
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReferencefish).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference1fish).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference2fish).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference3fish).delete()
                                        
                                    } catch {
                                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                print("Document does not exist")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Firestore.firestore().collection("PostsFish").document(documentfish.documentID).delete()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            postbirds.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for documentbirds in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        
                        let docRefbirds = Firestore.firestore().collection("PostsBirds").document(documentbirds.documentID)
                        docRefbirds.getDocument { (documentbirds, error) in
                            if let documentbirds = documentbirds, documentbirds.exists {
                                let databirds = documentbirds.data()
                                let imageReferencebirds = databirds!["imageReferenceID"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference1birds = databirds!["imageReferenceID1"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference2birds = databirds!["imageReferenceID2"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference3birds = databirds!["imageReferenceID3"]! as? String ?? ""
                                
                                Task {
                                    do {
                                        
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReferencebirds).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference1birds).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference2birds).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference3birds).delete()
                                        
                                    } catch {
                                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                print("Document does not exist")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Firestore.firestore().collection("PostsBirds").document(documentbirds.documentID).delete()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            blogs.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for documentblogs in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        
                        let docRefblogs = Firestore.firestore().collection("Blogs").document(documentblogs.documentID)
                        docRefblogs.getDocument { (documentblogs, error) in
                            if let documentblogs = documentblogs, documentblogs.exists {
                                let datablogs = documentblogs.data()
                                let imageReferenceblogs = datablogs!["imageReferenceID"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference1blogs = datablogs!["imageReferenceID1"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference2blogs = datablogs!["imageReferenceID2"]! as? String ?? ""
                                let imageReference3blogs = datablogs!["imageReferenceID3"]! as? String ?? ""
                                
                                Task {
                                    do {
                                        
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReferenceblogs).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference1blogs).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference2blogs).delete()
                                        try await Storage.storage().reference().child("Post_Images").child(imageReference3blogs).delete()
                                        
                                    } catch {
                                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                print("Document does not exist")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Firestore.firestore().collection("Blogs").document(documentblogs.documentID).delete()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            try await reference.delete()
            try await Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(userUID).delete()
            try await Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete()
            logStatus = false
        } catch {
            await setError(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите исправить ошибку.